# Custom List Row in Android leanback browser fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

in last 4 days i search through internet and android leanback library code to find my problem's solution, but i can not figure it out. in browser fragment of android leanback library it's explained how to have ListRowPresenter with two rows or more. but i want a row in browser fragment that look like something like this sketch:
[image]

any idea can helps a lot. thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I want to implement same. Can you please share if you get the solution.

Comment: nope i can not find solution

Comment: please clarify more on your sketch